# How can I create the list of items from different cardinal return value using Cypher from Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to create tabular format list of data lineage so that user can easily identify source table and columns from DWH tables using Excel filter function.
But the following Cypher code does not work.

```
MATCH(a:DB {TABLE:'CONT'})-[b:RELATED*1..3]->(c:DB)
WHERE ALL ( tmp IN b WHERE tmp.CLAUSE IN ['where','join','unknown'] ) 
RETURN a.table,a.column,b.clause,c.table,c.column
LIMIT 200
```

I got the following error.

```
Type mismatch: expected Map, Node or Relationship but was Collection<Relationship> (line 3, column 25 (offset: 147))
```

"RETURN a.table,a.column,b.clause,c.table,c.column"

If I specify only "RETURN a,b,c", I got the following.

```
a b c   
{"TABLE":"TXX","COLUMN":"CXX","DB":"DXX"}   [{"CLAUSE":"unknown"}]  {"TABLE":"TYYY","COLUMN":"CYYY","DB":"DYYY"}
```

But I want to get as below.

```
TABLE,COLUMN,DB,CLAUSE,TABLE,COLUMN,
"TXX","CXX","DXX","unknown","TYYY","CYYY","DYYY"
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

So, because the relationship you've bound to b is a variable length relationship of 1 to 3 actual relationships, when you reference b, you get a collection of those relationships, not a single relationship.

You can see that in your output when just using a, b, and c, note the brackets around the unknown clause; there could be up to 2 other objects in that collection. For some data, that "RETURN a, b, c" might look like this:

```
{"TABLE":"TXX","COLUMN":"CXX","DB":"DXX"}   [{"CLAUSE":"unknown"}, {"CLAUSE":"join"}, {"CLAUSE":"where"}]  {"TABLE":"TYYY","COLUMN":"CYYY","DB":"DYYY"}
```

That's why returning b.clause doesn't make sense, since you're asking for a property from a list instead of some kind of object.

You can probably do an UNWIND b as somethingElse...then do somethingElse.clause and have that work. UNWIND changes a list of something into rows, but be aware that if there are multiple :RELATED relationships, they will each appear in their own row in combination with a and c.